# IS there a way to Extract function app name from arm template file of CI Build during deplopyment to azure (CD) process

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

In azure devops CI pipelines i am deploying arm template for resource creation .In the release process how do i extract the resources created names from artifact so that i can refer to correct resource for deployment on azure

Comment: Do you use Az/AzureRM cmdlets to deploy? If so you can parse the output of the the PS script to get the names and other details during your CI/CD..

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the [`outputs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/template-outputs) section of an ARM template for this.

These values are recorded in the deployment created which you could fetch, either using the [`Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-3.1.0) or [`az group deployment show` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-deployment-show) as [documented in this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/template-outputs?tabs=azure-cli#get-output-values).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`  cmdlet here is what I do to get the json output.

```
$jsonOutput = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name  $DeploymentName `
        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -TemplateFile $TemplateFileToDeploy `
        -TemplateParameterObject $TemplateParameters `
        -Force -Verbose `
        -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages -DeploymentDebugLogLevel
```

Thereafter, I use either the `$jsonOuput.Outputs` which contain template outputs or the `$jsonOutput.Parameters` which in my case contains the `resource names` and other stuff.